# Task Scheduler in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scheduler

I asked this question before but unfortunately did not receive an answer.

I am writing a Spring Boot application. We send out over 1000 emails per day to our employees.

Since there is a limit on the number of emails I can send per hour, I want to send 99 emails per hour to the email addresses on my list.

I have the code that you see on your screens, how could I rewrite it with TASK SCHEDULER?

The mailing starts AFTER the send button is pressed on the front (I have an endpoint with a POST method
for this) mailing so I don't use a normal SCHEDULER with cron that runs at a specific time regardless of whether my controller method was called from the front.

```
Runnable task = () -> {

int counter = 0;
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (String emailAddress : usersEmailAddresses) {
    counter++;
    bulkEmailService.send(BulkEmailMessage.builder()
            .from(bulkEmailMessage.getFrom())
            .subject(bulkEmailMessage.getSubject())
            .content(bulkEmailMessage.getContent())
            .toAddresses(emailAddress)
            .build());

    if (counter % 99 == 0) {
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(6000 * 60 * 60 - endTime);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}

};
taskExecutor.execute(task);
```

Comment: This is a terrible solution and is brittle (if your server fails / stops it never sends the remaining parts). Instead create a task per email with a time on which it should be send, you also probably want to use Quartz for this with a persistent storage (or you could invent your own but I would advice against it).

Comment: This is one email with one content that must be sent to more than 1000 addresses.

Comment: I can't use the scheduler. Since my email will only be sent after calling my post method on the front side.

Comment: @M.Deinum  Please suggest me the best solution given that my email is only sent after the controller's Post method is called.

Comment: Reading is an art... Schedule the sending of the email **after receiving the post**. You can manually schedule your tasks. So again use a scheduler and schedule 100 emails in 1 task per email.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a database table that saves the task you want to execute when a user calls your endpoint. Then you can use a scheduler using the data saved in the database.

| Task | Cron | Execs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Email | 0 0 */1 * * * | 10 |